# WordPress Drop Down Menu issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the function below for my WordPress menu but every time I add a sub-menu, it doesn't show as it's supposed to.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'primary-menu', 'Primary Menu' ),
) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what's wrong without seeing more code or a site URL. But check your menu call in functions.php and in the template file (such as header.php) and the minimum css in the style sheet.

No reason to use Superfish within WordPress; WordPress 3+ menus are pure css and don't depend on javascript, and Superfish hasn't been updated in four years.

These are the basic functions and css from twentyeleven; use them as a basis for your own code.

functons.php :

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyeleven' ) );
```

header.php :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

style.css :

```
#access {
    background: #222; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#252525, #0a0a0a);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#252525, #0a0a0a);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#252525), to(#0a0a0a)); /* older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#252525, #0a0a0a);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#access a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 3.333em;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.333em;
    left: 0;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 168px;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #efefef;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #f9f9f9; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#e5e5e5)); /* Older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    color: #373737;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#access .current-menu-item > a,
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A submenu would be a CSS/jQuery issue.

Did you code the theme yourself? It's probable a

```
parent:hover child.sub-menu { display: block; }
/*Psuedo-code*/
```

type issue

Comment: No reason to use Superfish within WordPress; WordPress 3+ menus are pure css and don't depend on javascript, and Superfish hasn't been updated in four years.

Comment: Thanks for the note - I'll look into it. Removed from answer